# Youtube Data API v3 equlas empty cells for me

Tags: ios, uitableview, youtube, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking 2.4.1 to fetch YouTube thumbnails and the thing is I get empty cells when I use YouTube v3. I have no problem with v2.

What seems to be the problem in the below code?

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
            [manager GET:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&key={YOUR_API_KEY}" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                _objects = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"items"];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

            }];
```

Thanks in advance!